# how to change php extension into aspx extension using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'm new on php programming and i'm customizing an CRM base on PHP. I want to change the .php extension in .aspx, whether the php script is in the root file or sub directory, the .aspx should show up.
Here is my URL
I want to change THIS:

```
http://localhost/edev/pages/UI.php?operation=req
```

Into:

```
http://localhost/edev/pages/UI.aspx?operation=req
```

the code that i have tried
.HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://localhost/test/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://localhost/test/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Let me know if you have any question according to this question. Thank You :)

Comment: I cannot see any attempt to resolve requests to resources with a ".aspx" "file name extension" in your code. How do you expect us to help with that if you do not show your attempt? Your request is a pretty exotic one, btw, why would one want to show a "file name extension" in the web? That is so 80ish...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.aspx$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: When i enter this

`http://localhost/edev/pages/UI.php`

the browser redirecting me to this url

`http://localhost/pages/UI.aspx`

what does it mean.?

Comment: I fixed a typo in code. Update it. So what happens when you open http://localhost/pages/UI.aspx ? Is it open http://localhost/pages/UI.php page?

Comment: No i said when i visit this url
`http://localhost/edev/pages/UI.php`
the htaccess redirecting me to this url
`http://localhost//pages/UI.aspx`

Comment: @MohsinRaza I fixed example. Pls update it and try again.